# Find a div in another div and find a button in it and add a handler to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a div with class "row" which has the divs in it and each div has the buttons. I want to find the first div in "row" and the first button in it and add a handler to it. Here is what I've been doing in the different variations:

```
 $(document).on("click", "div.row div.my_class1:eq(0) .btn.my_class2:eq(0)", function() {
    alert("yes");
  });
```

I also tried this:

```
 $(document).on("click", "div.row > div.my_class1:eq(0) > .btn.my_class2:eq(0)", function() {
    alert("yes");
  });
```

and tried to remove white-spaces but had no luck.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle with the HTML?

Comment: @imbondbaby, no, it's a part big of code, I can't simplify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
  $(document).on("click", "div.row div.my_class1:first-child .btn.my_class2:first-child", function() {
     alert("yes");
 });
```